# Resize the graphical representation of the sound player (generated by Play)

Tags: play

How do I resize the graphic representation of the sound player in `Play`, as generated for example by

```
Play[Cos[1000 t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

without having to click-and-drag the player after it has been generated?

Same question for

```
ExampleData[{"Audio", "BlackcapWarbler"}]
```

I've examined all the `Options[Play]`, tried `Show`, and other obvious approaches, none of which worked.

---

(I fully expect this question will be closed as being covered in the documentation, but alas I simply cannot find it!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really the actual size control, but a trick for relative size. You can use

```
Magnify[Play[Cos[1000  t], {t, 0, 5}], .5]
```

or even something like

```
Magnify[Audio[Play[Cos[1000 t],{t,0,5}],Appearance->"Detailed"],2]
```

You can do the same for

```
ExampleData[{"Audio", "BlackcapWarbler"}]
```

but you need store data in the notebook first and that wrap `Magnify` around, otherwise it could break:

[image]

Comment: Yep.  Good enough for me... thanks ($+1$, $\checkmark$).  WRI should, though, include an Option such as `DisplaySize -> `.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DavidG.Stork -- I passed it to our teams.